# Laravel 5.7, preset bootstrap error. Failed to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to use the laravel 5.7 bootstrap4 preset, but have problems using it.
Do you guys know why I see this error? Why is the file missing? I have not changed the path to anything.

```
kgp43:~/workspace (master) $ php artisan preset bootstrap

In Bootstrap.php line 41:

copy(/home/ubuntu/workspace/resources/sass/_variables.scss): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you able to check what is inside the Bootstrap.php line 41: I'm pretty sure its a `require __DIR__` issues.

Comment: do you know where I can find bootstrap.php file? cant seem to find it :(

Comment: are you using sublime text editor?

Comment: No, i'm using c9.io. I searched all the files, and nothing shows.

Comment: have you already install the laravel bootstrap4 preset if not try this. `composer require laravelnews/laravel-twbs4` then
`php artisan preset bootstrap4`

Comment: To my understanding, the latest version of laravel (5.7) already support bootstrap4 preset. The problem is my auth templates, they are from an older version, and I want to replace them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

All folders in the Assets directory has to be moved up one level.
It should not be needed to move the content of the Assets folder (accoring to laravel - but it was for me to run the preset command.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade